# Nodejs Folder Path to load particular folder for frontend

Tags: node.js, path, angular5, mean-stack

I want to load www.xyz.com/frontend where I have all frontend code of angular4 in frontend folder. So, how I'm able to access it. What kind of change do i need in app.js?
any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Set a `Get` route returning `index.html` for you angular app.

```
 // return index html
 const path = require('path');
 app.get("/frontend", (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'index.html'));
 });
```

Comment: Cannot GET /frontend

Comment: Can you share the change you made.